# Find the data type of a structfield in dataset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a dataset, which has the following schema:

```
ds.schema()
    0 = {StructField@21690} "StructField(col_name_1,NullType,true)"
    1 = {StructField@21691} "StructField(col_name_2,StringType,true)"
    2 = {StructField@21692} "StructField(col_name_3,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(person_name,StringType,true), StructField(person_surname,StringType,true)),true),true)"
```

I want to access the datatype of each StructField. E.g. `if the data type of col_name_1 is NullType print null.`

How can I build this if loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can pull this [out of the schema:](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-find-datatype-column-names-of-dataframe/)

> ```
> for field in df.schema.fields:
>     print(field.name +" , "+str(field.dataType))
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me:

```
ds.schema().apply(ColName).dataType().toString().equals("NullType")
```